# What is the summation of some pseudo factorial?

Tags: summation

Given $n$ is a positive integer where $n>2$,
what is the summation of the following?

$$S_n=1+n+n(n-1)+n(n-1)(n-2)+\cdot\cdot\cdot+n!$$

Comment: Note that $S_n=1+n\cdot S_{n-1}$ and $S_1=2$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use  Don Thousand's comment $$S_n=1+n\, S_{n-1} \qquad \text{with} \qquad S_0=1$$ or 
Ng Chung Tak's answser, you have
$$S_n=e\, \Gamma (n+1,1)$$ where appears the incomplete gamma function.

This corresponds to sequence $A000522$ in $OEIS$ and it has, as generating function $\frac{e^x}{1-x}$.

The great Ramanujan gave as asymptotics
$$S_n=e\,n!-\frac 1{n}+\frac 1{n^3}-\frac 1{n^4}-\frac 1{2n^5}+\frac 1{9n^6}+\cdots$$

Answer (score 2):

> Using the exact expression of remainder term for Taylor series expansion:
>
> $$f(x)=\sum_{k=1}^{n}
>   \frac{f^{(k)}(a)}{k!}(x-a)^{k}+
>   \int_{a}^{x} \frac{(x-t)^{n}}{n!} f^{(n+1)}(t) \, dt$$

\begin{align}
  S_n &= n!
  \left[
   \frac{1}{n!}+\frac{1}{(n-1)!}+\ldots+\frac{1}{2!}+\frac{1}{1!}
  \right] \\
  &= n!
  \left[
    e-1-\frac{1}{n!} \int_{0}^{1} (1-t)^{n} e^{t} \, dt
  \right]
\end{align}